# Swift: array variable stored property is not mutable

Tags: ios, swift

In my app, i'm declaring an array stored property as a variable. when i want to check if it contains and object, Xcode doesn't autocomplete. If i complete it manually it shows an error saying that it doesn't contain this method. I think it the array is not being mutable although it's declared as a var. Here is my code:

```
class someClass{
   var someArray = AnyObject[]()

   func someFunction{
     if someArray.containsObject("object") <--- error here
   }
}
```

Comment: `containsObject` is not a method on `Array`, its a method on `NSArray`. There should be a Swift equivalent method to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code contains a bunch of syntax errors:

- There shouldn't be parentheses after `class someClass`
- There should be parentheses after `func someFunction`

But the error you noticed is that there is no method `containsObject` on `Array`. You can do:

```
contains(someArray, "object")
```

or you can cast it to an `NSArray`:

```
(someArray as NSArray).containsObject("object")
```

#### Edit

As Rob Napier correctly points out, the first option will (of course) only work on `String[]`, not on `AnyObject[]`. Swift really discourages mixed arrays.

Comment: Note that this won't quite work as written. The array needs to be of type String, not AnyObject for the generic to figure it out (you can't construct an AnyObject). But this is still the right approach.

Comment: thanks all working well, but with this i don't know why Apple is advertising the language as being easier to learn than Objective-C. Personally, I still find OC having some advantages over Swift. i Found it more readable though. I don't know if any one agrees too.

Answer (score 1):

`Array` doesn't have a method `containsObject`. That's a method of `NSArray`.

You can use the `filter` method for the `find()` function.

You could also cast the `Array` to `NSArray` then call the `containsObject`.